# Painfully slow opening webpages in Firefox when clicking on links in an email on Thunderbird (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, firefox, thunderbird

Here's the thing: I'm running updated Thunderbird and Firefox on updated Ubuntu 22.04

I just switched from Brave to Firefox and changed the default browser accordingly.

I have Firefox open with three tabs open.

When clicking on an hyperlink in an email on Thunderbird, it takes 4 seconds before Firefox starts loading that link.

Any ideas what to look for ?